What does ERC in Component box of Honorable Discharge form refer to?
I am reading through an Honorable Discharge for a relative who lived in New Mexico before and after his service in WW II. Basically I understand what has been written except for ther COMPONENT Space. I have looked for help and all I have found is that it refers to a country - like AUS for Australia. For Paul L Crane fis Component is ERC. My husband, a VietNam vet, and myself, daughter of a WW II Vet and a 30 year member of the National Guard who rose to the rank of Major, cannot figure it out.

ERC is the abbreviation for Enlisted Reserve Corps. Without seeing the entire document there is not much to go on to determine why that is in the component box. Some possibilities that it might indicate: the individual was placed in the reserves at some time due to injury, was there through some deferment, had volunteered into the reserves but had not yet been called to active duty, or that they were being discharged into the ERC having not completed full term of service at the end of the war.
